# rendering input fields depending on other selection

Tags: visualforce, javascript, picklist, inputfield

So I have a picklist which selects a type of reward this then should render certain input fields depending on which you option you select on the reward picklist. I got it to work with divs in HTML but I cant get it to work in apex code

Code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Reward Information">
        <apex:inputField id="reward" value="{!game.Reward_Type__c}"  onchange="checkRewardType()" />
        <apex:inputField id="cash" value="{!game.cash_amount__c}" rendered="false"/>
        <apex:inputField id="card_type" value="{!game.Card_Type__c}" rendered="false"/>
        <apex:inputField id="card_amount" value="{!game.Card_Amount__c}" rendered="false"/>
        <apex:inputField id="points" value="{!game.Point_Amount__c}" rendered="false"/>
        <apex:inputField id="custom" value="{!game.Custom__c}" rendered="false"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<script>
    function checkRewardType(){
            type = document.getElementById("reward");

            if(type.value== "Cash"){
                document.getElementById("cash").setAttribute("rendered","true");
                document.getElementById("card_type").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_amount").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("points").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("custom").setAttribute("rendered","false");
            }
            else if(type.value == "giftcard"){
                document.getElementById("cash").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_type").setAttribute("rendered","true");
                document.getElementById("card_amount").setAttribute("rendered","true");
                document.getElementById("points").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("custom").setAttribute("rendered","false");
            }
            else if(type.value == "points"){
                document.getElementById("cash").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_type").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_amount").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("points").setAttribute("rendered","true");
                document.getElementById("custom").setAttribute("rendered","false");
            }
            else if(type.value == "custom"){
                document.getElementById("cash").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_type").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_amount").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("points").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("custom").setAttribute("rendered","true");
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("cash").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_type").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("card_amount").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("points").setAttribute("rendered","false");
                document.getElementById("custom").setAttribute("rendered","false");
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the `rendered` tag from Javascript, the tag is part of the Visualforce page.

The easiest way to do this would be with a Javascript library like jQuery and than use a selector, and apply a method call like:

```
$('#myelement').show(); $('#myelement').hide();
```

**Tip:** When using Visualforce, the selectors that are ultimately rendered in HTML are not that easy to find with jQuery. So use a regex to find the element from the dynamically applied `Id` tags once the page is rendered:

```
$("[id$='txtTitle']")
```

Where `txtTitle` is the `id` attribute you assigned to an element in Visualforce like so:

```
<apex:inputField id="reward" value="{!game.Reward_Type__c}"  onchange="checkRewardType()" />
```

In this case it would be

```
$("[id$='reward']").hide();
```

Comment: To make it easy to find your VF Elements with jQuery, just give them classes.  Like styleClass="myClass" and then you can use j$('.myClass') to select those elements

Comment: Absolutely, classes are easier, but not always unique - and some VF elements don't allow for `dynamic ids`, or have a `styleClass` attribute, etc.

Comment: very true.  in my experience, classes are the way to go if you need a "`dyanamic id` when using `apex:repeat` but, obviously, can't generate VF `id`s dynamically.  (ex. `var="x"` and have `styleClass="myClass-{!x}") and most VF elements have the styleClass attribute (or you can work around to using one, like a `<div>` wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

This is becasue when VF renders, it changes the element IDs.  So even though you are specifying

```
<apex:inputField id="reward"/>
```

If you you right click and inspect the element in the page the id is actually something like

```
<input id="j_id0:j_id1:Pageblocktitle:pageblocksectiontitle:reward" type="text">
```

So your script is not finding an element with an Id of 'Reward', because it doesnt exist.  So you either need to match your script to use the proper IDs that are createdc when the VF is rendered, or I would suggect using jQuery.  Then you could find that ID that ends in your id.  Use something like this

```
   j$('[id$='reward']')
```

This finds the element where the Id ends with 'reward', which does match your inputfield.  Then you can use .show() and .hide() to render the fields

Hope this helps